# Nesting data to each UID in firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to create a reading list app, and want to nest a reading list under the users uid, so I can just show their list to them when they login. The code I have working is this:

```
var items: [ReadingItem] = []
let usersRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "users")
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "reading-list")
var user: User!
var userCountBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem!
```

However this gives me nodes of data, users, and reading-list. I tried changing the code to the section below, but it gives me an error of "Cannot use instance member within property initialiser; property initialisers run before 'self' is available"

```
var items: [ReadingItem] = []
let usersRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "users")
let ref = usersRef.child(self.user.uid)(withPath: "reading-list")
var user: User!
var userCountBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem!
```

So finally I tried changing it to this, but it gives me an error of "Cannot use instance member within property initialiser; property initialisers run before 'self' is available"

```
var items: [ReadingItem] = []
let usersRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "users")
let ref = self.usersRef.child(self.user.uid)(withPath: "reading-list")
var user: User!
var userCountBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem!
```

Obviously very new to Swift, but any help on this would be really appreciated!

Comment: What specifically are you asking? How to write code to create a reading list node within your users node or how to read that node... Or how to display it in a tableView? Do you have proposed Firebase structure? If you can clarify the question we can probably answer it.

Comment: Hi @Jay - I'm asking how to change my code so the reading list node is a child of the uid. Displaying in the tableView I can get my head around, but it's this first step I'm really stuck on. Proposed Firebase structure would be this:

Users
— uid1
     — reading list
— uid2
     — reading list

Comment: Do you want to know how to create that node or to read in the node or both? Or something else?

Comment: Sorry - it wouldn't let me edit the comment after 5 minutes, so here's how that should have finished:

Hi @Jay - I'm asking how to change my code so the reading list node is a child of the uid. Displaying in the tableView I can get my head around, but it's this first step I'm really stuck on. Current Firebase structure is [this](http://i.imgur.com/faVdtpk.png). Proposed structure would be [this](http://i.imgur.com/rqn2bVr.png). Thanks!

Comment: Both would be great. But I'd settle for just how to create that node for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you want to able to create users within a users node and each user will have a child node with that users reading list.

The structure would look something like this

```
users
  uid_0
    age: "37"
    name: "Larry"
    reading_list:
        item_0: "Discovery"
        item_1: "Astronomy"
        item_2: "Popular Mechanics"
```

To create this structure, here's one way of doing it:

```
let readingListDict = [
    "item_0": "Discovery",
    "item_1": "Astronomy",
    "item_2": "Popular Mechanics"
]

let userDict = [
    "name": "Larry",
    "reading_list": readingListDict,
    "age": "37"
] as [String : Any]


let usersNode = self.ref.child("users")
let thisUser = usersNode.child("uid_0")
thisUser.setValue(userDict)
```

this to read the node, we use an observer like this

```
    let thisUserRef = self.ref.child("users").child("uid_0")

    thisUserRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let userDict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
            let name = userDict["name"] as! String
            let age = userDict["age"] as! String
            let readingList = userDict["reading_list"] as! [String: Any]
            print("name: \(name)  age: \(age)")
            print("  list: \(readingList)")
        }
    })
```

and the output is

```
name: Larry  age: 37
  list: ["item_1": Astronomy, "item_0": Discovery, "item_2": Popular Mechanics]
```

The above code is just one way and very verbose and with much error checking.

To expand further, if you know the users uid and that user node already exists, you can simply write to the reading list child node directly

```
let thisUserReadingListNode = self.ref.child("users").child("uid_0").child("reading_list")
thisUserReadingListNode.setValue(readingListDict)
```

Comment: This could work @Jay - although I'll be storing a few other things in the reading list (url, read time, etc) so will need to expand on this. Thank you though, this is really helpful

Comment: @NigelThornberry Glad it helped! Make sure to accept the answer so it can help others as well.

Comment: Haven't had time to check it works in my code, but will accept it as an answer - thanks again!

Comment: @NigelThornberry Let us know if you need any other help with the answer. Otherwise, accept it when you've had time to review!

Comment: Sorry Jay, last one then I will close this. Won't this save it to specific "uid_0" rather than the generic uid? My previous code of "(self.user.uid)" worked in other places to great a uid node, it was just not nested where I wanted it to be

Comment: @NigelThornberry uid's are not generic. Well, they are generic in form but not in function. uid's are created when the user is initially created in Firebase, and therefore that's the time to create your users node with that user.  /users/-UYijs9ja9msdasdk and /users/-Y8i899ajsjdijias is how it would typically look. Your comment is correct, if a user is authenticated, you get their uid with auth.uid, and that would go in the place of uid_0 in my answer. I get tired of making up uid's (-Yin89j89993) so I just use uid_0 etc. lol.

Comment: Riiiiiight ok sorry, I misunderstood. Thank you so much! Marking as correct now!

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know the context you are putting this in, I am assuming you are trying to call this in a `UIViewController`. If you are doing this in a `UIViewController` you may want to try doing the following.

Declare your variables like this:

```
var items: [ReadingItem] = []
var usersRef: DatabaseReference?
var ref: DatabaseReference?
var user: User!
var userCountBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem!
```

Then in `viewDidLoad()`, do this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.usersRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "users")
    self.ref = self.usersRef?.child(self.user.uid).child(withPath: "reading-list")
}
```

Comment: Hi Justin - sorry. This is in a TableViewController, above viewDidLoad(). I tried your suggestion and it gives an error "Cannot call value of non-function type 'FIRDatabaseReference' - any suggestions?

Comment: I updated the code. To fix this error, make sure to call `.child` after `.child(self.user.uid)`

Comment: Ok progress! It fixed one error but throws another: "Thread 1: exc_bad_instruction(code=exc_i386_invop,subcode=0x0)"

Comment: Without seeing more of your code or a runnable version I don't know what could be wrong.

Comment: Added it to a sandbox here so you can see the code in this file http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/596c43b6d6db2c1b527371a0. If you can spot anything that's throwing that error please let me know

Comment: Do you have a callstack?

Comment: Not that I know of